# I have transferred (all) my files from my SD Card (phone) to my computer and my android phone ( Galaxy S9) is frozen. What can I do to save the phone?

Tags: samsung

[image: this is my folder after transfer]

My phone froze and won't respond to anything, what can I do ?

my internal storage is still full ( pics and docs all from there is still in the phone )

I thought of transferring those files in picture back to the SD card but I doubt it would do anything.(Would this work)?

There's also a write protection on the card.

Also, there's an android & system folder from the phone's SD Card that got transferred as in the picture above. Would that have caused my phone to freeze and be unresponsive?

Comment: check [Lacking storage booting](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3885938) option from [recovery mode](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-galaxy-s9/recovery-mode)

Comment: I can't go to recovery mode. My phone won't respond to any gesture and press from the physical buttons .The screen is frozen.

Comment: okay I was able to go to the recovery mode, which option to choose , n the next steps to make sure all files aren't deleted..?   what will the lacking storage booting do ?

Comment: *lacking storage booting* will boot a phone that won't boot because of lacking storage

Comment: Press and hold the power button for up to 60 seconds. Usually this initiates a farced reboot.

Comment: The phone resolved the prob. The phone was stuck and after I waited for the battery to die, the phone rebooted as usual and was fine. I wonder if its because the android or the main "important" folders aren't rewritable or can't be deleted....